# How can Wordpress Access/Updates Two Databses Simultaneously

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have two Different hosting accounts, One is VPS and another is shared Hosting. 
I am running my wordpress website on a VPS server. My Database is also hosted there.
I want to keep the copy of my Database in Shared Hosting as well so that whenever a update is done on Website it store same data on both Databases, one copy on live DataBase (VPS) and another one on the shared hosting DataBase (for backup purposes).

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure if this is what you're asking for, and I'm sorry in advance if it's not.

Now, you can connect to a second wordpress database (or a third etc.) like this:

```
$your_db = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
```

You can also read more here:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pros-and-cons-of-adding-tables-to-the-wp-db?replies=8#post-1201613